Mutex Queue(?) for an Azure DevOps pipeline
I'm creating a build which will dynamically provision an Azure environment via a resource group and then deploy a bunch of stuff to it. To save time, I'm staging a single environment ahead of time, queuing the creation of another environment, and deploying to the old one - that saves me the runtime of creating the environment, assuming that there aren't a bunch of deployment requests stacked up.
Creating the environment isn't terribly difficult - we'll create a resource group, name it dynamically, and then use that as a hook for the deployment stuff. The question is - how do I store and retrieve the name of the environment? The important thing is that I want the name locked when two builds do run at the same time. That is, if two builds are coming in at about the same time, I want the build that wins the race to get the name and prevent the other build from getting it. The other build would then queue the creation of another environment, and get the name when it was completed.
I could probably just use Azure storage, but I'm concerned about contention. I could use a queue...service bus? Not sure what the right tool for this simple an application is.
For bonus points, this is going to end up in Github Actions at some point, so something that is readily scriptable in Actions would be helpful.
TIA.

Considering your solution is already all-in Azure, consider using https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/blobs/storage-blob-lease to solve the synchronization problem. Azure Storage was made to scale (e.g. 20K TPS is supported) and you can find more details at https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/common/scalability-targets-standard-account.

Why can't you just use the build ID or a version number or some other unique value for the dynamic name? It sounds like you're creating a whole big problem when just using something like Build.BuildNumber or Build.BuildId would be a 10 second solution.

@DanielMann I think you might be right.

The downside is that I cannot provision an environment ahead of time. There could be failed builds in between, or CI builds, or who knows what.


"queuing the creation of another environment, and deploying to the old one"- Are you doing it in the pipeline? If so, how did you archive it? It's better to share your yaml.  2. What exactly is the "environment name" you are talking about? Resource group name? Resource group tag? Or something else? 3. What you mean by "cannot provision an environment ahead of time"? Did you create an RG in advance before creating the pipeline? Every time the pipeline is built, a new RG must be created first and then deployed to the old RG?


No YAML yet, nothing built. But essentially, new RG every time, with a tag that designates it this kind of RG (mostly so it can be deleted once it's done being used). Name can be anything. The whole point is to be using a pre-existing environment to deploy to and then building one to replace the one you just used, to save provisioning time.

From Azure DevOps perspective, I agree with Daniel Mann's suggestion: Use a unique value for the dynamic name from DevOps. I understand that you can't provision an environment ahead of time. But if you use parallel jobs to create and deploy to multiple RGs at the same time, you can also save time.

@ZiyangLiu-MSFT That's the solution I'm going to go with initially. I may need the pre-provisioned environment down the road, but I'm going to treat this whole exercise as premature optimization for the time being...

Perhaps you can also submit a feature request, requesting variable groups lock. In this way, you can store the created RG name in the variable groups and prevent subsequent builds from accessing it through lock.

There is an exclusive lock, but it cancels all the old runs and permits the latest run to be deployed, which is the opposite of what you want.
